# ¿Qué significa not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature) en la sintaxis XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Estoy firmando un documento XML y en el ejemplo de la firma que debo construir  el elemento XPath posee el valor
 not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)

Mi pregunta es la siguiente en sintaxis Xpath ese valor tiene algún equivalente o debo escribir ese valor literalmente como aparece en el ejemplo de la firma ?

```
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
<ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath>
</ds:Transform>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El nodo `ancestor-or-self` indica el nodo de contexto (o actual) y todos sus antecesores, incluyendo el nodo raiz.

Comment: Hola ...Sergio Parra Guerra ...Entonces NO esta mal colocarlo de esta forma  <ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath>

Comment: En principio no

Comment: ¿Como asi que en principio no?Podrias ser mas especifico...

Comment: Perdón. NO está mal lo que has escrito